# How do I obtain joint distribution of uniform random variables conditioned on a sum constrain?

Tags: joint-distribution

Let us say, we have two random variables,
x1 --> U(10,20) i.e. x1 is uniformly distributed between 10 and 20, and
x2 --> U(20,40) i.e. x2 is uniformly distributed between 20 and 40.

Moreover, it has to be ensured that x1+x2 = 40 always.

How do I compute the joint distribution P(X1,X2|X1+X2=40)?

In other words, how do I find joint distribution based on a sum constraint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The joint *density* function of continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ *conditioned* on $X+Y=a$ does not exist. Conditioned on $X+Y=a$, the random point $(X.Y)$ is *constrained* to lie on the straight line through $(a,0)$ and $(0,a)$ and so doesn't have a joint density in the sense of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ telling you how *dense* the probability mass is in the vicinity of $(x,y)$: the units are probability mass per unit *area* and since $(X,Y)$ is constrained to lie on a line (which has zero area!), the only nonzero "value" we can ascribe to the *joint* density is $\infty$.  What we *do* have is a line density measured in probability mass per unit *length*.

Comment: I really want to thank you for answering my question, I really really appreciate it. So basically, what happens is if we are given n measurements each of which are uniformly distributed within certain intervals, and that the total sum of the n measurement is always constant, the joint density always loses a degree of freedom.

If n=3, then instead of evaluating probabilities on volume, it is evaluated on surface. Could you please give an example of how to actually compute it? I tried by writing out the joint pdf of two uniform densities but was unable to accomodate the sum constraint